# A firewall without any extra features

Tags: network, firewalls, windows

I have Kaspersky Internet Security (KIS) installed on my system. I always keep it disabled, yet using a few practices, I kept my system virus free for years:

- I disabled autorun using [these tricks](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/889747);
- I installed the freeware [Panda USB Vaccine](http://www.pandasecurity.com/homeusers/downloads/usbvaccine/);
- Every time I get a new file from the web or by other means, I run KIS on it. When in doubt, I check it using [VirusTotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com). If still in doubt, I run it via [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/);
- I keep my Windows & other software updated.
- I enabled Windows Firewall.

Believe me or not, these simple tricks made my system 100% immune against malware.

However, while keeping KIS disabled frees the system of performance degradation, there is one drawback: Programs can freely access the web.

I need a lightweight firewall (for Windows XP) which does not have any extra features; that is, it only controls the connection. There are many free/commercial firewalls, like [Comodo](http://personalfirewall.comodo.com/), [ZoneAlarm](http://www.zonealarm.com/), [Outpost](http://www.agnitum.com/products/outpost/), [Privatefirewall](http://www.privacyware.com/personal_firewall.html), etc., but they have a lot of extra features, like **Application Integrity Check** and other application controls (whether an app can create/terminate process, can use interprocess communication, can setup hooks, etc.).

To sum up:

> I need a lightweight firewall which is capable of setting what apps can access what ports/protocols/etc., but does not bother me with other application checks.

**Edit:** Anyone has experience with [Jetico Personal Firewall](http://www.jetico.com/firewall-jetico-personal-firewall/)? It seems to be very lightweight (the installer package is about 3.5 MB). I recall an older version once ruined my XP and I had to reinstall it. Yet newer versions might have come with bugfixes.

Comment: Similar to my answer to [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/758/33), it's important to note that this will only block low hanging fruit. More complex malware *will* be able to bypass this, if you're running it on your endpoint. One way or another.

Comment: @AviD: Sure, but I'm not after protecting from malware. As I said, I'm pretty sure that malware is not lurking on my system. I just want to find what apps try to connect (say, for instance, to check for an update), and prevent them if needed. Legal apps usually do not use dirty tricks to circumvent a firewall.

Comment: "Usually" being the operative word ;)

Comment: You say "100% immune" which is just plain wrong.  Besides malware which may slip thru, there are many zero-day attacks out there for most any complex application which accesses either the Internet or other data over which you have no control.

Comment: @nealmcb: Yes, in theory that's right, but I didn't experience such disaster for years.

Comment: @SadeqDousti - http://www.cartoonstock.com/newscartoons/cartoonists/mba/lowres/mban1987l.jpg

Comment: Jetico reminds me of Visnetic. You won't find *any* application integration in that. The rules you set up will be purely based on network interface cards, protocols, IP addresses and port numbers... a truly *minimal* firewall to be certain (though there might also be a neat *tarpit*), *without any extra features* (except perhaps for the neat *tarpit*) to be certain, but you seem to want one *with extra features which allow rules based on processes (and process integrity)*. You should try some of those which you listed...

Comment: On another note, as others have mentioned, you've not exhausted the mechanisms that viruses use to propagate. Common viruses nowadays tend to attack software vulnerabilities in your web browser, iTunes services, a poorly written software firewall, your OS or any number of other components, in order to infect your computer. How are you planning to defend yourself against those? There's only one mechanism I can think of, and that would be to prevent modification to the filesystem; use a livecd for example, and make sure you keep that up-to-date. This leaves you a HD purely for cache&data.

Comment: From there it should be known an infection can still occur, but will disappear when the system is rebooted. You could achieve a similar effect using encryption; store the public key on a separate SD card to the private key, use private to sign your disk and public to verify the signature and theoretically, you should be able to verify your disk with a single pass of the drive. I'm not sure if anyone has done this. If you don't plan on writing a lot of data to your system drive, nand flash might get cheap again soon. I scored some 32GB 633x which reaches approx 80MB/sec about a year ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After over 3 years, I found my answer.

[TinyWall](http://tinywall.pados.hu/) is a "free, lightweight and non-intrusive firewall". (Just 1 MB !)

The only thing I wish it had is a log of recently processes blocked by TinyWall, or any other way to inform me when a process is blocked for the first time (and perhaps, subsequent times).

Beyond that, I thing **everything** is excellent.

Comment: TinyWall does not work on Windows XP. But after 3 years, I'm no longer working on Windows XP :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the built in Windows Firewall?  It does exactly what you've asked and is extremely lightweight.

Comment: Windows Firewall usually warns when an application wants to bind to a local address (i.e. work as a server). But it does not warn otherwise. For instance, I recently installed a new web browser, and it does not warn me when I wanted to access to web via it (the browser didn't have a digital signature).

Comment: Right, but you can still lock it down so only approved applications can connect outbound using a whitelist.  IMO you'd be better off if something didn't pop up and just blocked it by default.

Comment: Note that "approved applications" is something that can also be misused, abused, and bypassed. E.g. via DDE, automation, DLL hooking, etc. In effect it has low value against (custom) malware, but it does give you some element of control on standard apps.

Comment: @AviD: As I told, I'm sure malware is not present on my system. Yet I want to know what apps try to connect (directly), and restrict them if I wanted. AFAIK, Windows Firewall does not provide this functionality. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I understand that note, but important to point out (as you say, control not security). Also you are mistaken re Windows Firewall - but it depends which version Windows. On 7, you can go to the Advanced section and create per-program rules.

Comment: @AviD: Sorry, I must have pointed that I'm on XP.

Comment: @Sadeq, you're right - sorry, I missed that. Regardless, this might help you (or someone else) in the future :). On XP the firewall is very limited - inbound by port/subnet only.

Answer (score 0):

When I'd previously looked at firewalls on MSWindows (admittedly some time ago), kerio stood out as being significantly more secure and manageable than any other product available.

At that time I believe it was available in a free evaluation version - but this appears to have been withdrawn leaving only the paid for version.

Comment: Well, I took a look at it. Kerio Control is about 70 MB, which is far from being lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

In your comments I read you're still on XP (you should edit that into your question) - for that I suggest trying to get hold of an old version of ZoneAlarm. It blocks everything out-of-the-box (unlike the Windows firewall) and always asks permissions for new and changed programs, and does nothing else. Basically the permissions asked are 'accessing the trusted zone', ''accessing the internet', 'trying to act as a server', but you can fine tune things. If you are behind a router (NAT) you can fiddle with your ports there.